# How to save inherited class using astyanax?

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I am unable to save child class data with the persistence of parent class using astyanax in cassandra.

I created the child object with all necessary data, but when I try to store that object, only values from the parent class is stored, not from child object.

Here is the sample Code not real:

```
@Entity
class Shape{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column
    private String name;
}

@Entity
class square extends Shape{

    @column
    private int width;
}

now to store I am using EntityManager of  astyanax.

square s=new square();
s.setName("sqaure");
s.setWidth(100);
s.setId("1234");
EntityManager em= //initialization code
em.put(s);

after doing this only "name" and "id" is stored into database. not width.
```

Comment: can you post some relevant code?

Comment: I added the sample code.

Comment: A shot in rhe dark, but check the case on the annotation on width. Other than that,  seems like a bug in the framework.

Comment: Case is not a problem. it's @Column only. it's a sample code which I wrote here, so have case problem. It seems there is a bug in their framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EntityManager` requires the type of the entity via the `withEntityType()` method.  This type is used to build an `EntityMapper` via reflection which then determines the fields to serialize.  There is nothing in the [Entity persistence documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Entity-persister) or examples that says Astyanax supports polymorphism.  This is not a bug, just a feature that doesn't exist.  You will need a type-specific `EntityManager` for each subtype of your base class.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer to use Hector instead.